# FHIR: Using a relative date in Search or Subscription Criteria

Tags: hl7-fhir

Is it possible to use a relative date or calculated value in either a search request or a subscription criteria?  This is especially necessary in subscription criteria, as the criteria value is saved in a resource.

I would like to be able to provide functionality like this:

Subscribe to all patients where the patient is less than 2 years old.
Search for all patients that are over 65 years old.
Search for all observations in the last week.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to define custom search criteria that involve some sort of calculation or inference on the part of the responding server, though obviously this increases the complexity for the server responding to the query.  Once defined, these could be used for subscriptions as well.  If you think there's broad utility for a particular derived query parameter, you can propose it for inclusion in the specification as well.